# django - eventmonthview 404 instead of empty template and getting the month prior

Tags: python, django

im using the MonthArchiveView and have used the url to send the year and date of the previous month.

however when i click it i get a 404 with the following:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://it.service.com/maintenance/previous/2016/04/
Raised by:  maintenance.views.EventMonthArchiveView
No Planned IT Maintenance available
```

i dont know why it is not showing the empty page instead of this? should i not be getting the is empty template instead of this?

also i want to know how to take the current month/year from the url and minus 1 month off it if a users clicks the previous link again, and again (each time a user clicks previous they get the previous month

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta, time

from django.views.generic.dates import MonthArchiveView

from .models import Maintenance
from .models import MaintenanceType
from .models import ServiceType

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    today = date.today()
    ObjMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(StartTime__gt=today)

    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', {
        'Maintenance': ObjMaintenance,
    })

def thirtydays(request):
    today = date.today()
    previous_month = (today.replace(day=1) - timedelta(1)).replace(day=1)
    ObjMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(StartTime__gt=today-timedelta(days=30))

    return render(request, 'maintenance/previous.html', {
        'Maintenance': ObjMaintenance,
        'previous_month': previous_month,
        'Title': 'Maintence in the Last 30 Days',
    })

def previous(request, year, month):
    previousMnths = datetime
    ObjMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(StartTime__gt=today-timedelta(days=30))

    strPrevious = 'Maintence for the month %s' % (previous_month)
    return render(request, 'maintenance/previous.html', {
        'Maintenance': ObjMaintenance,
        'previous_month': previous_month,
        'Title': strPrevious,
    })

def upcoming(request):
    today = date.today()
    ObjMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(StartTime__gt=today+timedelta(days=30))

    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', {'Maintenance': ObjMaintenance,})      

class EventMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    template_name = "maintenance/previous.html"
    queryset = Maintenance.objects.all()
    date_field = "StartTime"
    allow_future = False
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'maintenance'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^thirtydays/$', views.thirtydays,  name="thirtydays"),
    url(r'^previous/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/$',
        EventMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'), 
        name="previous"),
    url(r'^upcoming$', views.upcoming, name='upcoming'),
]
```

template url

```
<a href="{% url 'maintenance:previous' previous_month|date:'Y' previous_month|date:'m' %}"><< Previous Maintenance</a>
```

Comment: I think the month archive view already works as you want. On the May 2016 page, `previous_month` will be `2016-04-01`, and on the April 2016 page, the `previous_month` will be `2016-03-01`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display an empty list instead of 404 when there are no events, set [`allow_empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-date-based/#django.views.generic.dates.BaseDateListView.allow_empty) to `True` for your month archive view.

```
class EventMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    template_name = "maintenance/previous.html"
    queryset = Maintenance.objects.all()
    date_field = "StartTime"
    allow_future = False   
    allow_empty = True
```